# Android gradle build error "if the artificant you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven Pom' format

Tags: android, maven, gradle, nexus

i use Android Studio now
and i have some problem to gradle build

my error ->
if the artificant you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven Pom' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources {..}' of the repository declation

i can't use network, because i have offline workspace.
so i can't use mavenCentral(), google()... on <build.gralde>
how can i fix it?
answer please ..
thank you

Comment: What artifact triggers this?

Comment: You have to create local repository (lot of works) and add mavenLocal()